# create Line break/new line after fwrite() PHP

Tags: php, forms, newline

Hello I am trying to write a php file that edits a text file. However I have a set of variables that each come from separate html form inputs. I want each of those values to display on a new line. I tried using PHP_EOL, "\n", and "\r\n". Below is my code. I hope someone may give me guidance. Note that everything works smoothly, except inserting a new line

```
<?php
$file="file.txt";
$fh=fopen($file , "a+");
$input1=$_POST['input1'];
$input2=$_POST['input2'];
$input3=$_POST['input3'];
fwrite($fh , $input1. " " . $input2 . " " . $input3 . "\n");
?>
```

Comment: What happen if you use `\r\n` ?

Comment: nothing at all. As I keep submitting my form with data in it, the data keeps being added to the file and the line gets longer.

Comment: How do you use `"\r\n"` ? Have you tried `"\n\r"`. Is `"\n"` already valid?

Comment: Maybe you missed the `\n` at the end of your file. So when want to add a new line, it gets added on the same line instead.

Comment: How are you viewing the generated file?

Answer (score 1):

Try replace:

```
fwrite($fh , $input1. " " . $input2 . " " . $input3 . "\n");
```

With:

```
fwrite($fh , $input1 . PHP_EOL . $input2 . PHP_EOL . $input3 . PHP_EOL);
```

As for me, it's working.

Comment: Well thank you very much. I've got it partially working. The text in the file that PHP is reading is the way it is formatted. The display however, still shows as a whole string. Any ideas on this @CORRUPT ?

Comment: try `echo '<pre>' . file_get_contents($file) . '</pre>';` if it's in html markup.

Comment: @user2235005 then `'<pre>...</pre>'` should help.

Comment: @user2235005 Also, since this file contains user-contributed content, it would be better to `htmlentities()`/`htmlspecialchars()` before you output to HTML.